# Vue store dispatch single property instead whole object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I was wondering if it is possible, to dispatch only a single property to vuex store instead the whole object. There are no possibilities written in [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html). Currently I store object like this:

```
store.dispatch('currentUser', {
  memberData: 'fooBar'
});
```

Some times I just want to fetch only a single value from database and push it into store. Is there a way to do that?

#### UPDATE

I think my question is unclear.

Actually I need to access a child nested property of memberData in dispatch, to change only one element of memberData. To be honest, it does not matter what response is. It could be 'foo' as well.

Comment: Is the goal to send `response[0]` as a payload without needing to assign it to a property `memberData`? Or do you mean sending a property of `response[0]`? Assuming `response[0]` is equal to `{ name: "foo" }`, do you mean you want to send the value of `name`?

Comment: Actually I need to access a child nested property of `memberData` in dispatch, to change only one element of `memberData`. To be honest, it does not matter what `response` is. It could be `'foo'` as well.

Comment: Okay, is `memberData` stored in the `store`? Is the goal to "merge" a change to specific property with the existing `memberData` object in the store? Do you know what property will be changed? Or are you planning to send an object with key/value pairs to represent the changes needed? Can you update your question, ignoring Vue/Vuex, and show what you want to do in pure JavaScript? What your original object looks like and how the changes coming would be used?

Comment: Yes, it is stored in `store` and I also use `state`, `mutations`, `actions` and `getters`. `memberData` is an empty object in `state` and  will be dispatched with payload. Now `memberData` contains `propA: 1, propB: 'bar'`. After that I just want to change the value of `propB` and not the whole object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you review the documentation for [dispatch](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch), the 2nd argument `payload`, can be any type. It doesn't necessarily need to be an **object-style dispatch** nested in a property:

Dispatch:

```
store.dispatch('currentUser', response[0]);
```

Store:

```
state: {
  currentUser: undefined
},
mutations: {
  setCurrentUser(state, currentUser) {
    state.currentUser = currentUser;
  }
},
actions: {
  currentUser(context, payload) {
    context.commit('setCurrentUser', payload);
  }
}
```

Mutation:

```
setCurrentUser(state, currentUser) {
  state.currentUser = currentUser;
}
```

Here is a [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8xqyn9s4/2/) in action.

**Update:**

If the goal instead is to merge/update changes, you can use spread in [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). This is also mentioned in the Vuex documentation for [Mutations Follow Vue's Reactivity Rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules).

Dispatch:

```
store.dispatch('currentUser', { systemLanguage: response[0].systemLangId });
```

Store:

```
state: {
  memberData: { systemLanguage: 'foo' }
},
mutations: {
  updateCurrentUser(state, updates) {
    state.memberData = { ...state.memberData, ...updates };
  }
},
actions: {
  currentUser(context, payload) {
   context.commit('updateCurrentUser', payload);
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wjp9zt6g/2/) of that in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The update solution by merging the objects sounds very cool! I'll check that! Will accept after that. Thx.

Comment: Is there also a way in `dispatch` to reach child elements of `memberData` and changes it? It's syntactically not working, but I'll show you what I need: `store.dispatch('currentUser', {memberData.systemLanguage: response.systemLangId});`

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your data structure is (in your question data `response` is an array), but I updated the answer and the linked live example to show how you change that property. You don't need to do `memberData. systemLanguage` as the `{ ...this.memberData, ...updates }` merges properties together.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!